# ngModel works only as output

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

Consider a class:

```
 export class MyClass {
      a: string;
      b: string;
      getProperties(): string[] {
        return [this.a, this.b];
      }
    }
```

There is an Angular2 component, which has a field of type `MyClass`. In it's template, there are these lines:

```
<span *ngFor="let property of newElement.getProperties(); let i=index">
        <input [(ngModel)]="newElement.getProperties()[i]" class="new-rest-type" placeholder="property">
      </span>
```

When component renders, it properly show contents of each property, both `a` and `b`, but if I type something inside of `<input>`, it does change value displayed on the page, but does not change the value inside of `newElement`. Any ideas why it behaves like that?

**Also**, `MyClass` field is declared in a super component.

**UPDATE** for @Aravind:
Let's say, I want to make two components, which would behave similar and show names of persons inside a table, where one row corresponds to one person and each column corresponds to each name. In different countries persons can have different amount of names, so it goes like this:

```
export abstract class Person {
  public abstract getNames(): string[];
}

export class RussianPerson extends Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  public getNames(): string[] {
    return [this.firstName, this.lastName];
  }
}

export class IcelandPerson extends Person {
  firstName: string;

  public getNames(): string[] {
    return [this.firstName];
  }
}
```

Now, I want to have some `AbstractPersonNamesComponent`, which would have two subclasses: `RussianPersonNamesComponent` and `IcelandPersonNamesComponent`. They will have the same template, which will have an `*ngFor` inside, where we will display names for each person, using second `*ngFor` to browse through result of `getNames()`. It should look smth like this:

***Russian Persons:***

|Leonid  | Borisevich|

|Vasiliy | Petrov    |

***Iceland Persons:***

|John  |

|Thomas|

Comment: are you trying a typeahead search box?? also your input tag does not have type attribute. update your post with component content

Comment: I am trying to build an hierarchy of components, which would diplay tables in common way, but tables may have different amout of rows (depends on how many fields subclasses of `AbstractMyClass` have)

Comment: this is not the right way. give me more information I will guide you to achieve your hierarchy of components.

Comment: @Aravind I updated the question, pls have a look

Comment: In both the cases **getNames()** method will return an undefined object. as there is no data passed. Also your class cannot have properties and methods. this should of **Injectable()** in angular2

Comment: @Aravind why is it undefined? It's an array of strings if I do `var returnValue: string[] = [];
    returnValue.push(this.firstName);
    return returnValue;`, result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It looks like if you use `*ngFor` for array of primitive types (`number`, `boolean`, `string`) it passes variables inside itself by value and not by reference, so when you change it inside of `*ngFor` with `ngModel` - nothing happens. So the solution is to wrap values inside of some class and put elements of that type inside an array instead of primitive type. I did it like that:

```
export class Valuable<T> {
  constructor(str: T) {
    this._value = str;
  }

  private _value: T;

  get value(): T {
      return this._value;
  }

  set value(value: T) {
    this._value = value;
  }
}
```

Then just make `firstName: Valuable<string>` and it works fine.